# Showing ListView outside ScrollView android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I have a particular `LinearLayout` where I have multiple components. I have a `ScrollView` in which I have another `LinearLayout` with a `ImageView`, two `TextView`s and `Button`s. I also have a `ListView` at the very bottom of the page which shows comments. The problem is I want the `ListView` to show completely without any scrolling. The `ListView` scrolls giving a bad design. If I place the `ListView` outside the `ScrollView`, it does not show.

Here is my code:-

details.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="38.7dp"
        android:background="#FF3C6FA6"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageBackBtn"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:background="#FF3C6FA6"
            android:fadingEdge="none"
            android:src="@drawable/btnbackclickedxml" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <!-- Main  vertical LinearLayout-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:id="@+id/layoutList">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <!-- Layout for Date, Likes, comments and views -->
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="98dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtPubDate"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#F8F8F8"
                        android:textSize="11sp"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnViews"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:src="@drawable/btnviewpressed" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtViews"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="view"
                    android:textColor="#FF3C6FA6"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnComments"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/btncommentpressed"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtComments"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#FF3C6FA6"
                    android:text="view"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgNewsImage"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/abc" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtBody"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/btnComms"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Comments" />

                <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/btnAddComms"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Add Comments" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/android:list"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/getdata" 
                android:divider="#b5b5b5"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" 
                android:padding="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Listview will scroll if it have components more than the height of the listview. What you need is to programmatically set th height of the listview by calculating the items within that.

Comment: @Viswanath the ListView dynamically adds items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take scrollview and Listview inside a one parent LinearLayout and assign weight for both , this may help you..

Answer (score 0):

As per sending code in your problem you have used scroll view height with match_parent. To resolve this you have to set fixed height in your xml file or in your java file by get reference of your scroll view